# Found some 404s for image files in statistis

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api, http-status-code-404, facebook-sharer

I am running a website in which I generate dynamic images for users. Initially, I was saving all the images generated forever so that I can use those images when required to be shown again but since recently I started getting some decent traffic, so I thought instead of saving and reusing the images I should generate them again when they need to be shown again.

Now what I am doing is: I have created a temp folder and I save every image in that temp folder and show it to user. And when this image is required to be shown again, I just re-create that image instead of using this temp image. And temp folder is now emptied at sometime daily.

But now I have started getting 404s in my error logs for the images. I am not getting that from where I am getting those 404s since I myself tried deleting image from tmp and then revisited that page. The image was re-created and was shown properly. I am badly stuck at this. One thing I would like you to tell is that I am allowing user to share those result-pages(with images) on social networks.

So it is like:

1. I create one image in tmp and show it on some result.php page. I
   also put the image's link in og meta tag so that it can be properly
   identified by social networks while sharing.
2. If somebody visits result.php page again, then it shows image again. However, if image is not available(i.e. deleted as daily
   job), then it recreates it first, saves at that location and then
   shows the page.
3. I am getting 404s for .jpg image files in error log.

On debugging it more, I found that these 404s are there because of access to images from Facebook IPs. The IPs from which 404s are detected are like: `66.220.158.119, 173.252.101.116, etc`. On some googling, I founf that these IPs are allocated to Facebook.
So it means: facebook bot is accessing the images because these links were earlier shared on facebook via facebook share. Can someone please tell me is there any harm if later(say after 1 day of sharing), if facebook does not find the image anymore on my server? Will it not show anymore on shared link on facebook also?